# how to login to rally1.rallydev.com for the very first time?

Tags: javascript, linux, rally

For the first time how we can login to https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/login.op

I have googled it, but not getting any exact steps

Comment: Did you ask their support?

Comment: Yeah, I'd follow up with either your company's subscription admin or Rally support to figure out your user acct.

Comment: Thanks , but can you do it asap please